# MySQL count/sum fields

Tags: mysql, count, sum

What I am trying to achieve is a report on daily financial transactions. With my SQL query I would like to count the total number of cash transactions, the total cash value and the same for checks. I only want to do this for a specified date.

Here is a snippet of the query that I am having trouble with. These sum and count commands are processing all the data in the table and not for the selected date.

```
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TRANSACTION WHERE payment_type.name = 'cash') AS total_cash,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TRANSACTION WHERE payment_type.name = 'cash') AS total_cash_transactions
```

Sorry if I havent posted enough detail as I haven't time. If you need more info just ask..

Cheers.

UPDATE:
I have posted some more info on the layout and results i'm getting here:
www.conorhackett.com/sql/transaction.html

The problem is that when I join the payment_table (so I can specify payment_type_name instead of id) It counts all the transactions for cash/cheque. The date limitation seems to disappear.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "and not for the selected date"... which selected date?

Comment: Where is the 'WHERE transactionDate='2010-04-10' part of your query? I'd expect something like 'payment_type.name=... AND transactionDate=...'

Comment: I'm not sure if mysql does this, but in oracle to sum over all days you could do a sum(X) partition over transactionDate

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for correlated subqueries, just use `group by`

```
select
 t.payment_type_id as type_id
,sum(t.amount) as total_cash
,count(*) as total_cash_transactions
from TRANSACTION t
where t.date = '2010-05-01'
group by t.payment_type_id
```

You can then join the result with `payment_type` if you need to get the type names from there.